# ImagePicker dismiss tabBar Nav Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Tab Bar Controller that presents a NavigationController.  In one of the ViewControllers I push on top of this I add the imagePickerController to select a photo.  When I cancel or select a picture the tab bar disappears...  I tried to look for answers but I could not find one that referenced my specific issue.

Here is my Image Picker Method

```
    @IBAction func attachImageBtnTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary){
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
            imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext
            self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        attachImageBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

How can I avoid this?  I tried to see if I had set the tabar to be hidden somewhere like in viewWillAppear but No.

Any ideas, any help would be very much appreciated !

Comment: The moment I tap cancel the tabbar slides(animated) down

Comment: @Matt It is not hidden....

Comment: if self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden == true{
            print("hidden")
        } else{
        print("not hidden")
        }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the error, I need to present the imagePicker Controller 'OverCurrentContext'.

```
   @IBAction func attachImageBtnTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary){
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
            imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
            self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Saved the day mate! Cheers!